# Importing csv files based on part of file name only in r

Tags: r, csv, file, opencsv, read.csv

I have two questionnaires that automatically assigns the date of the download in the file name. I want future researchers to be able to download the files and use the r code without having to change the file name.

So instead of being

```
questionnaire1.csv
questionnaire2.csv
```

they get downloaded as

```
questionnaire1_February 24, 2022_06.16.csv
questionnaire2_February 24, 2022_06.17.csv
```

Is there a way I can make r just take the first part of the name like:

```
q1 <- read.csv("Path where your CSV file is located on your computer\\questionnaire1*.csv")
q2 <- read.csv("Path where your CSV file is located on your computer\\questionnaire2*.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search files using a pattern:

```
q1 <- read.csv(list.files("your/path/", full.names = TRUE,
      pattern = "questionnaire1")[[1]])
```

Comment: I get: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection -------
and: In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'questionnaire1_February 24, 2022_06.16.csv.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: @VictorNielsen try my revised answer